# Use different version of Jhipster

Tags: npm, jhipster

I have a project built with Jhipster 3.0.0.
I want to create a new project with version 3.12.2. So I have upgraded Jhipster :

```
npm update -g generator-jhipster@3.12.2
```

Then I ran yo jhipster in the empty directory of my new project, but it's still using 3.0.0 version.

What do I need to do in order to use the 3.12.2 version?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `npm install -g generator-jhipster@3.12.2`?

Comment: It works with install. Thanks